# Postgres get last update id

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-update

How can i get the last update id in postgresql session?

```
UPDATE table1 set title = 'something' WHERE id = 13; 
SELECT lastval(); --returns 13
```

Comment: `lastval()` won't return anything unless you have called `nextval()` before that. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pg_get_serial_sequence(table_name, column_name)` along with `CURRVAL` like

```
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table1','id'));
```

See Here for more information on the same [System Information Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following query:
It will return the id of last updated tuple ( NOTE: Insert query also has similar behavior)

UPDATE table1 set title = 'something' WHERE id = 13 returning id;